# Class sentinel.groups does not exist

Tags: laravel, sentinel

After I made a composer update, I get this error:

> Class sentinel.groups does not exist

Any suggestions?

Using: Laravel with Cartalyst Platform and Sentinel.

If you need to see some code, let me know.

- Removing cartalyst/sentinel (dev-master 6749d28)
- Installing cartalyst/sentinel (dev-master 08d5c12)
  Downloading: 100%

Answer (score 1):

you need to pull in the changes from the Platform repository or apply these changes https://github.com/cartalyst/platform/commit/08fcd8b00bf1c0cd8bdca7fb6990dc168c2a02da on your composer.json manually, after that you can run composer update and it should work as normal.